# Visualstudio 2017 show "property pages" instead of Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

When I use "Properties" from the context menu (or hit alt+enter) in a dotnetstandard project VS2017 shows the "Property Pages dialog" instead of the properties window.
In other project this works as expected. Is there a way (setting) to change this behavior?
[image]

Comment: You will have to paste screen shots.

Comment: Added a screen shot

Comment: It seems to be by design. Use Help | Send Feedback menu items to report to Microsoft and see if they can fix that.